# Google geocharts with coordinates?

Tags: google-visualization

I want to use google geochart with coordinates (longtitute, latitute). But I cant find any example about this topic. There are a lot of example with region and city example. But with coordinates I Cant find.

Please, code example, link, tutorial any thing else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart):

> Marker location [Required] The first column is a specific string
>   address (for example, "1600 Pennsylvania Ave").    OR The first two
>   columns are numeric, where the first column is the latitude, and the
>   second column is the longitude.

You need to define first two columns of your data set as numeric values representing latitude and longitude.

Comment: I know. I understood this. But I cant do this. Is there any example?

Answer (score 14):

You can check an example here:

```js
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['geochart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

  function drawVisualization() {var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

 data.addColumn('number', 'Lat');                                
 data.addColumn('number', 'Long');
 data.addColumn('number', 'Value'); 
 data.addColumn({type:'string', role:'tooltip'});                        

data.addRows([[41.151636,-8.569336,0,'tooltip']]);
data.addRows([[ 39.059575,-98.789062,0,'tooltip']]);
                               
 
 var options = {
 colorAxis:  {minValue: 0, maxValue: 0,  colors: ['#6699CC']},
 legend: 'none',    
 backgroundColor: {fill:'transparent',stroke:'#FFF' ,strokeWidth:0 },    
 datalessRegionColor: '#f5f5f5',
 displayMode: 'markers', 
 enableRegionInteractivity: 'true', 
 resolution: 'countries',
 sizeAxis: {minValue: 1, maxValue:1,minSize:5,  maxSize: 5},
 region:'world',
 keepAspectRatio: true,
 width:400,
 height:300,
 tooltip: {textStyle: {color: '#444444'}}    
 };
  var chart = new   google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('visualization')); 
     
    
 
 chart.draw(data, options);
 
 
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?fake=.js"></script>
<div id="visualization"></div>
```

There are many ways to do it, this is just one.

```
data.addColumn('number', 'Lat');                                
data.addColumn('number', 'Long');
data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
data.addColumn({type:'string', role:'tooltip'});                        

data.addRows([[41.151636,-8.569336,0,'tooltip']]);
data.addRows([[ 39.059575,-98.789062,0,'tooltip']]);
```

Comment: Great, even showing up the coordinates inside the results looks little bit odd. Here is a modified version with label names instead of the coordinates: http://jsfiddle.net/WpYrE/1/