# How to change Default color in google charts geomap?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, geomap

I want to change the default yellow color of chart region to user defined color. I can able to change only marker color. I used this code to generate chart data.

```
         dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
         dataTable.addRows(4);
         dataTable.addColumn('number', 'LATITUDE', 'Latitude');
         dataTable.addColumn('number', 'LONGITUDE', 'Longitude');
         dataTable.addColumn('number', 'Ticket', 'Value'); 
         dataTable.addColumn('string', 'HOVER', 'HoverText');

         dataTable.setValue(0,0,12.9715987);
         dataTable.setValue(0,1,77.5945627);
         dataTable.setValue(0,2,43);
         dataTable.setValue(0,3,"Banglore");

         dataTable.setValue(1,0,22.642664);
         dataTable.setValue(1,1,88.439122);
         dataTable.setValue(1,2,66);
         dataTable.setValue(1,3,"Kolkatta");

         dataTable.setValue(2,0,13.0826802);
         dataTable.setValue(2,1,80.2707184);
         dataTable.setValue(2,2,54);
         dataTable.setValue(2,3,"Chennai");

         dataTable.setValue(3,0,9.9252007);
         dataTable.setValue(3,1,78.1197754);
         dataTable.setValue(3,2,64);
         dataTable.setValue(3,3,"Madurai");
```

[image]

How to change the region, background and tooltip color? please help me

Answer (score 0):

There is a a [ticket on github for this](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/65)

Basically the code below set's the options your need

```
var options = {};
  options['region'] = 'US';
  options['resolution'] = 'provinces';
  options['colorAxis'] = { minValue : 0, maxValue : 1, colors : ['#FF0000','#0000FF']};
  options['backgroundColor'] = '#FFFFFF';
  options['datalessRegionColor'] = '#E5E5E5';
  options['width'] = 556;
  options['height'] = 347;
  options['legend'] = 'none';

  var geochart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(
      document.getElementById('visualization'));
  geochart.draw(geoData, options);
```

this is also covered in the [official docs](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart#coloring)

> ### backgroundColor
>
> The background color for the main area of the chart. Can be either a
>   simple HTML color string, for example: 'red' or '#00cc00', or an
>   object with the following properties.
>
> Type: string or object Default: white
>
> ### backgroundColor.fill
>
> The chart fill color, as an HTML color string.
>
> Type: string Default: white
>
> ### backgroundColor.stroke
>
> The color of the chart border, as an HTML color string.
>
> Type: string Default: '#666'
>
> ### backgroundColor.strokeWidth
>
> The border width, in pixels.
>
> Type: number Default: 0

Comment: geo charts doesn't have Banglore,Chennai like city codes for india :-( that's why i used latitude longitude value to map the coordinates using geomaps

Comment: [You should be able to use lat and long in a geochart too](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11878259/542251)

Answer (score 0):

Hey this worked for me

```
colors: ['#0077CC']
```

You can add this in Options Like :-

```
var options = {
    region: 'IN',
    displayMode: 'markers',
    colorAxis: {colors: ['blue']}
  };
```

For more information you can visit [Link](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart)